# Vector differentiation of Mean Squared Error

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, vectors

I have a set of notes where it states the following,

S = $(\mathbf{y}- \mathbf{X} \boldsymbol{\theta})^{\text{T}}(\mathbf{y}- \mathbf{X} \boldsymbol{\theta})$

$\frac{\partial S}{\partial \boldsymbol{\theta}} = -2\mathbf{X}^{\text{T}}(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\theta}) $

(Assume $\mathbf{X}$ is a matrix, $\mathbf{y}$ and $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ are vectors all of suitable dimensions). So essentially, S is the squared error, $\mathbf{X}$ is the design matrix and $\mathbf{y}$ is a vector of observations and I need to find the $\theta$ that minimises S, but I'm having trouble with differentiation. My working is as follows,

$(\mathbf{y}- \mathbf{X} \boldsymbol{\theta})^{\text{T}}(\mathbf{y}- \mathbf{X} \boldsymbol{\theta})= (\mathbf{y}^{\text{T}} - \boldsymbol{\theta}^{\text{T}}\mathbf{X}^{\text{T}})(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\theta}) = \mathbf{y}^{\text{T}}\mathbf{y} -\mathbf{y}^{\text{T}}\ \mathbf{X} \boldsymbol{\theta}- \boldsymbol{\theta}^{\text{T}}\mathbf{X}^{\text{T}} \mathbf{y} +\boldsymbol{\theta}^{\text{T}}\mathbf{X}^{\text{T}} \mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\theta} \\ \text{Diff. w.r.t.} \ \boldsymbol{\theta} \text{ yields}; \\ 
\frac{\partial {S}}{\partial \boldsymbol{\theta}} = - \mathbf{y}^{\text{T}}\ \mathbf{X} - \mathbf{X}^{\text{T}} \mathbf{y} +2\mathbf{X}^{\text{T}} \mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\theta} $

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with vectors and matrices, you have to be careful about the dimensions of quantities. Assuming $y$ and $\theta$ are column vectors, then $X^Ty$ and $X^TX\theta$ are column vectors, but $y^TX$ is a row vector. So the expression $-y^TX-X^Ty+2X^TX\theta$ doesn't make sense.

You should get $\dfrac{\partial S}{\partial \theta} = -2X^Ty + 2X^TX\theta$. Now, simply set this equal to $\vec{0}$ and solve for $\theta$.